# Visual Studio 2010 IDE exception thrown by the target of invocation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I can't launch VS 2010 (on Windows XP), every time this error "exception thrown by the target of invocation" keeps showing.
I have checked the length of PATH variable, it is under 2048 so this is not the cause.

What else might cause the problem?

Comment: Sounds like it's "uh-oh I probably need to reinstall VS" time :(

Comment: Believe it or not, I did reinstall it, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

seems like Windows explorer causes this issue, I am not sure.

My OS: Windows 2008 R2 (using as desktop), running VS 2010 and VS 2013 both.

When I started VS 2010 today morning, got this exception:exception thrown by the target of invocation.

I killed the explorer.exe from task manager, and started again use the task manager File->New Task -> Explorer.exe.

Start VS 2010 - Worked fine.

Hope this helps